# Record videos simultaneously with both of iOS device's front and back cameras

Tags: ios, video

Is it possible to record videos simultaneously with both front and back cameras? I have seen apps doing this for capturing images, but I have not seen a single app recording video simultaneously from both front and back camera.

Comment: The image capturing apps are probably use the cameras not simultaneously. I think they just switch them in quick succession.

Comment: Even I felt the same @kelin. So you mean there is a hardware restriction to do this feature implementation?

Comment: I don't know. It will be better if you ask someone from Apple.

Answer (score 2):

From the [AVFoundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW25):

> **Note:** Media capture does not support simultaneous capture of both the front-facing and back-facing cameras on iOS devices.

Comment: And do you have any idea about the same thing in Android? @rob mayoff

Comment: I don’t know anything about Android media capture.